# Render HTML Webpage to text in Java

Tags: java, html-parsing

I would like to get the text representation of a website in a *human*-readable form, for example hyperlink locations or input fields.
Is there any library that does this? (I've checked Jericho Renderer but it does not show input fields)
For example

```
<div>
<form action="example.php">
Name:
<input type="text" name="name_field">
<input type="button" value="OK">
</form>
</div>
```

to something like this

```
Name: [________] [OK]
```

Comment: HTML *is* the text representation of a website. Please give an example.

Comment: Ok, edited the question to have an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [tag soup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) and build it yourself. You get a DOM model of the HTML and can spit out the text.